# Access other values ​in a trigger before save Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

Is it possible to access the previous values ​​that have not yet been stored in the database?

I have a table related to a particular module (**MOD**) which I will call table **XA**.
I can insert multiple records into XA simultaneously they are going to be inserted, I cannot change this fact.

For example, the following data is inserted in **XA**

```
ID | ParentId | Type | Name  |  Value

1  |    1     |  5   | Cost  |  20000
2  |    1     |  9   | Risk  |  10000
```

And I need in this case to insert / update a record in this same table. A calculated value

At the moment of executing the trigger, the value with the name of Cost for example is inserted first, and then the value of Risk.

When evaluating the Risk, I must have the ability to know what the Cost value is to make the calculation and insert the calculated record.

I tried to create a Package to which I would feed the data, but I still have the same problem.

---

```
create or replace PACKAGE GLOBAL
IS
   PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;

   TYPE arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (32)
      INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (50);

   NUMB   arr;
END GLOBAL;
```

---

```
//Using in trigger
GLOBAL.NUMB (:NEW.ID || '-' || :NEW.ParentId) := :NEW.Value;
BEGIN
     IF :NEW.Type == 9 AND GLOBAL.NUMB (5 || '-' || :NEW.ParentId) IS NOT NULL
     THEN
        // calculate and insert record
     ELSE IF :NEW.Type == 5 AND GLOBAL.NUMB (9 || '-' || :NEW.ParentId) IS NOT NULL
        // calculate and insert record
     END IF;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
     THEN
     // NOT HAVE TWO INSERT TO SAME REGISTER
END;
```

Values ​​5 and 9 are for reference.

Both records are not always inserted, one or more can be inserted, even the calculated value can be imputed but must be replaced by the calculation.

And I can't create a view since there is an internal process that depends on this particular table.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Does the same transaction always insert the COST and RISK records?

Comment: APC: The same records are not always inserted. It depends on the user, there is a panel in which the user can impute the values ​​and when clicking on save, all the records will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *really really* must store calculated value into a table? That's usually not the best idea as you have to maintain it in any possible case (inserts, updates, deletes).

Therefore, another suggestion: a **view**. Here's an example; my "calculation" is simple, I'm just subtracting `cost - risk` as I don't know what you really do. If calculation is very complex and should be run every time on a very large data set, yes - performance might suffer.

Anyway, here you go; see if it helps.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From xa order by parentid, name;

        ID   PARENTID       TYPE NAME      VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----------
         1          1          5 Cost      20000
         2          1          9 Risk      10000
         5          4          5 Cost       4000
         7          4          9 Risk        800
```

A view:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_xa as
  2  select id,
  3         parentid,
  4         type,
  5         name,
  6         value
  7  from xa
  8  union all
  9  select 0 id,
 10         parentid,
 11         99 type,
 12         'Calc' name,
 13         sum(case when type = 5 then value
 14                  when type = 9 then -value
 15             end) value
 16  from xa
 17  group by parentid;

View created.
```

What does it contain?

```
SQL> select * from v_xa
  2  order by parentid, type;

        ID   PARENTID       TYPE NAME      VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----------
         1          1          5 Cost      20000
         2          1          9 Risk      10000
         0          1         99 Calc      10000
         5          4          5 Cost       4000
         7          4          9 Risk        800
         0          4         99 Calc       3200

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't replace the table with a view. There is an internal process which I cannot control. I must do it using the trigger so that when creating the values, they are reflected without refreshing the page.